# Front-end rich text editor with option to add link to Sitecore media library item

Tags: sitecore, rich-text-editor

I'm currently working with Sitecore 8 Update 2.

I would like to have a rich text editor on a webpage with the possibilty to add a link to a document/picture from the media library (this is for an intranet implementation should you have security related issues).

I've found some rich text editors like CKEditor and TinyMCE but nothing that already implements some Sitecore functionality (if this exists it would be great if you could point me towards that).

Would it be possible (and not too much trouble) to create a dialogue screen in an existing Rich Text editor that can select an item from the Media Library?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the one from Sitecore itself and try to place it on your page. The path to the rich text editor is **Website\sitecore\shell\Controls\Rich Text Editor**

Thanks

Comment: If you use the one from Sitecore then make sure you are licensed to use the Telerik controls on your own site. Sitecore's implementation license will not cover you outside of the CMS.

Comment: This isn't really helpfull to use somewhere other than the Content editor. It's sort of premade for it. It's very hard to present this functionality properly ( like when you want to add a document )